# Why my working sticky divs don't work inside <iframe>?

Tags: html, css

I have sticky elements on my page. It works as I want. But after I got the page inside an iframe, all sticky elements become static.

Tried to change every parent div with `overflow: unset;`, (even iframe and upper) it didn't help.

```
#accessBar {
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #e8eeff;
    position: sticky;
    width: calc(100% - -40px);
    bottom: -1px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details and `html`?

Comment: I am not sure if i can. There are a lot of html code. Not 50 as usual here. But really a lot.

Comment: Try to add what is necessary to clarify what is your problem or create jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Styling for `IFrame` should be within the `IFrame` itself.
Note that the `Sticky` rule will apply WITHIN the `IFrame`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <style>
  iframe { height:200px;   border: 0; }
  </style>
  <p>Your Page with Some Content...</p>
  <iframe srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id='accessBar'>AccessBar</div>Long Document Ahead:<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>End of Long Document<style>html, body{ min-height:100%;position:relative} #accessBar {
  background: #e8eeff;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
}</style></body></html>"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S
I have used an inline `IFrame` so i wont have to create a page somewhere to host it.

Answer (score 0):

Position:sticky does appear to work if you have a scrollable iframe: <iframe scrolling="yes"...

The content is sticky in relation to the iframe's scroll bars, not the host page's.

The height of the iframe content must overflow (be larger than) the specified iframe height.